# How to select specific overlapping pattern using Cypher?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, overlapping

I have a dataset with nodes and relationships in Neo4j. Something like this:

```
(a)-[r:sel]-(x)
(a)-[r:sel]-(y)
(a)-[r:sel]-(z)
(a)-[r:sel]-(w)
(b)-[r:sel]-(z) 
(b)-[r:sel]-(y)
(c)-[r:sel]-(z)
```

Nodes x,y,z and w have the label DEP with properties (ex: DEP.type).
y and z have the same property (DEP.type are defined equally).

I would like select just nodes such as (b) but not nodes such as (a).
In other words, the nodes only in area written below:

[image: Overlapping]

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Best wishes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Scenario 1

This query returns a collection of all the nodes that have a `sel` relationship with `a`, if and only if the collection has multiple nodes and all of them have the same `type` value.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:sel]-(x)
WITH a, COLLECT(x) AS col, LENGTH(COLLECT(DISTINCT x.type)) AS numTypes 
WHERE numTypes = 1 AND LENGTH(col) > 1
RETURN a, col;
```

## Scenario 2

This query returns a collection of all the nodes that have a `sel` relationship with `a`, if and only if the collection has multiple nodes and the entire collection has a specified property with a specified value (in this example, `type = foo`).

```
MATCH (a)-[r:sel]-(x)
WHERE x.type = 'foo'
WITH a, COLLECT(x) AS col
WHERE LENGTH(col) > 1
RETURN a, col;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would like to return this result such a list of a.property, x.property..

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you see the overlapping figure, this query selected specific nodes in junction of two oval areas (where I wrote 'this area') and other two oval areas above (specific junction of others two oval areas - below). I would like just one junction using something like x.property = 'something'. Complementary, the result such as x.property2, a.property1. I hope I have been clearer. Best

Comment: I have added a second scenario to my answer. Does that answer your actual question? (I think my first answer does answer the question as you wrote it originally.)